# omnet++ 5.0 installation .eclipse_keyring

Tags: installation, omnet++

I have just installed the latest **Omnet++** version on my Macbook Pro with OS X El Capitan.
When I start Omnet++ from the launcher icon, it show me the following warning message:

> ```
> <b>"file doesn't exitst, ignoring: /Users/Jonathan/.eclipse_keyring"</b>
> <br>
> ```

If I start the app from terminal, it doesn't show me any message. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but probably Eclipse will create the necessary file and next time will not prompt you or you can try creating manually

```
$ cd /Users/Jonathan
$ touch .eclipse_keyring
```